# Having Trouble in Callin the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

So I am making a java program that quizzes students on the capital of the USA states.(I am fairly new to JAVA) Okay guys so here is part of my program:

```
class SetUpButtonActionListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

        for(int i=0; i < state.size(); i++)
        {
            question = (String)(state.get(i));
            //i++;
            countryName.setText(question);
        }

    }

}
```

The problem is when I am trying to call the `ArrayList` one by one in the `SetUpButtonActionListener` class. It runs fine, but when I click on the `New Problem` button its supposed to show each one state and ask the user for the capital(haven't gotten to this part yet). However, when I click the button it doesn't show up with anything. I am not really to sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: does it throw any error

Comment: No it doesn't throw any error it says "build successful" and fails to show anything in the contryName TextField.

Comment: whats the exception log ?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean with "exception log". Do I have to create a try-catch exception?

Comment: where have you called the `stateName()` method?

Answer (score 3):

`state` **is and will remain** empty until you call `stateName()`. This explain the observed behavior.

You probably want to add a call to `stateName()` at the beginning of your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you should call filling method of your list in the constructor

```
public QuizPanel()
{
            stateName()
            setUpButton = new JButton("New problem!");
            add(setUpButton);
            setUpButton.addActionListener(new SetUpButtonActionListener());
            ...
             }
```

Comment: THANKS YOU!!!!!! That just helped me out a lot. I cant beleive I was missing something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to call `stateName()` to fill the array.

Second, this way you did, every time the button is clicked, the method `actionPerformed` is called, and the loop runs with all the values of the array, always finishing getting the last value.

What you need is to maintain a value pointing to the next value of the array, so this way, every time you click the button, only the next item is got.

```
class SetUpButtonActionListener implements ActionListener{
    int currentIndex = 0;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //verify if the index is inside the array (reseting it if not)
        //get the value
        //increase the index
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I just realized that I was fixing my previous mistake.